# How to separate thousands from a Float value with decimals in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following Float: `1123455432.67899`

My desired result is a String: `1,123,455,432.67899`

Best case correct `,` and `.` based on location (US/Europe)

```
struct Number {
    static let withSeparator: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.groupingSeparator = ","
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()
}

let myFloat: Float = 1123455432.67899
let myNumber = NSNumber(value: myFloat)
let formatter = Number.withSeparator
if let result = formatter.string(from: myNumber) {
   print(result)
}
```

This formatter works great as long as my Float has no decimals, als soon as I'm having decimals it starts to "calculate". It calculates up/down based on the 3rd decimal number.

What am I missing? What's the best way to get a `String: 1,123,455,432.67899` from a `Float` with no matter how many decimal numbers? Help is very appreciated.

Edit:

My exact function:

```
func formatValue(_ value: String ) -> String {

    if let double = Double(value) {

        let formatter = Number.withSeparator
        if let result = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: double)) {
            return result
        } else {
            return value
        }
    } else {
        return value
    }
}
```

`value` is always a number for example `5.5555555555`. But in this specific case the `result = 5.556`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to specify the `grouping` separator as `,`? Not all places use it.

Comment: no i don't need to have the separation forced by `,`, it was just example code

Comment: A `Float` is a 32-bit binary floating point number. It can represent approx 7 decimal digits, compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point. For precise *decimal* arithmetic, use `(NS)DecimalNumber`

Comment: For a general understanding, take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.

Comment: thank you for the links @MartinR !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Double` instead of `Float`, the value you are specifying is not well representable in `Float`:

```
// [... your current code ...]
let myDouble: Double = 1123455432.67899
let myNumber = NSNumber(value: myDouble)
// [... your current code ...]
```

> 1,123,455,432.679

The `e+XX` notation `Float` has by default is not just for show, it is there because `Float` cannot store all digits. See:

```
let myFloat2: Float = 1123455432.67899
print(myFloat2 == 1123455432) // true
let notRepresentable = Float(exactly:1123455432.67899) // nil
```

Comment: it doesn't really helps my problem. if i use the exact code but with double and i put in decimal numbers, it starts to change the number from the 3rd decimal on

Comment: my in put = 5.5555555555, output = 5.556

Comment: @DavidSeek You get 3 decimal places because that's the default for the number formatter. Use `formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 9`.

Comment: FYI - no need for `myNumber`. You can use: `formatter.string(from: myDouble as NSNumber)`.

Comment: @rmaddy the maximumFractionDigits with Double in combination did it. thank you

Comment: and the myNumber was just to have everything as self explained in my question as possible

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, your issue comes from the floating point imprecision of `Float`. Using a double precision floating point data type (`Double`) will alleviate this, to an extent.

Also, you shouldn't hardcode the `groupingSeperator`, but instead let it be inferred from the current locale (which is the default behaviour).

```
import Foundation

let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let nf = NumberFormatter()
    nf.numberStyle = .decimal
    return nf
}()   


let myDouble = 1123455432.67899
let myNumber = NSNumber(value: myDouble)

// It's also directly initializable from a literal
// let myNumber: NSNumber = 1123455432.67899 

guard let result = numberFormatter.string(from: myNumber) else { fatalError() }  

print(result)
```

Comment: No need to set the formatter's locale to the current locale - that is the default.

Comment: Btw no need to initialize a new NSNumber object. just use for: instead of from:

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [luk2302's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43297607/5501940), I would suggest to add it as a method to a `Double` *extension*, as follows:

```
extension Double {
    func formattedString(_ maximumFractionDigits: Int = 5) -> String? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = maximumFractionDigits

        return numberFormatter.string(for:self)
    }
}

if let formattedString = 1123455432.67899.formattedString() {
    print(formattedString) // 1,123,455,432.67899
}
```

It might improve the ease of getting the desired string.

*Thanks for [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) and [@LeoDabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) for providing useful notes.*

Comment: What's the point of the `guard` statement? Simply return the result of `numberFormatter.string`.

Comment: Do not set the groupingSeparator. Let it default properly based on the user's locale.

Comment: Btw no need to initialize a new NSNumber object. just use for: instead of from:

Comment: @LeoDabus could you please elaborate?

Comment: `string(for: double)`

Comment: @LeoDabus pretty cool! I didn't know that I am able to do such a thing, in my mind, there was a -wrong- guideline says: when working with `NumberFormatter`, there is must be a used `NSNumber` for reading it. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Now you can extend FloatingPoint instead of Double

Comment: I would also move your formatter out of there. Make a static property extending Formatter protocol so you can use it without initializing a new Formatter every time you use it

Comment: @LeoDabus I've already tried to make the extension to be of `FloatingPoint`, but because the `NSNumber` is unable to take one a a parameter, I made to be an extension of `Double`, after getting rid of  the `NSNumber`, it would be legal. Please feel free to edit my answer :)

Comment: Using for instead of from you can just change it as it is

Comment: @LeoDabus Referring to your comment "I would also move your formatter out of there. Make a static property extending Formatter protocol so you can use it without initializing a new Formatter every time you use it", -when you are available-, could you please show us how it should be done? as a noob developer I'll be very happy if I learnt something new today... :)